# Getting the same error: "Warning: Received NaN for the children attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string."

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tried fixing it multiple times and looked over it multiple times but keep on getting the same error: "react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Received NaN for the `children` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string."

Need help reviewing this code below and see why that error keeps on showing up

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

function BlackjackGame() {

    // useState will return a tuple where the first parameter ()
    //  ...is the current state of the deck. () allows us to update
    // ...the state of the deck.

    const [deckFilled, setDeckFilled] = useState(false);

    // declaring a new state variable for the card deck
    const [cardDeck, setCardDeck] = useState({});

    // PLAYER :
    // declaring a new state variable for the player
    const [gamePlayer, setPlayer] = useState([]);
    // declaring a new state variable that holds the player points
    const [playerPoints, setPlayerPoints] = useState(0);
    // new state variable for optional player points
    const [optlPPt, setOptlPPt] = useState(0);
    const [showOptlPPt, setShowOptlPPt] = useState(false);
    // new state variable for the player cards
    const [enablePlayerCards, setEnablePlayerCards] = useState(true);
    // new state variable for the when the player is done with their round
    const [endOfPlayerRound, setEndOfPlayerRound] = useState(false);
    // new state variable for the player buy-in
    let playerCurrentBuyIn = 5000;
    const [playerBalance, setPlayerBalance] = useState(playerCurrentBuyIn);


    // GAME :
    // setting the variable for the bet
    const[currBet, setBet] = useState(0);
    // game round
    let round = 3;
    const [gameRound, setGameRound] = useState(round);
    // game bet
    const [placeGameBet, setPlaceGameBet] = useState(true);
    // game message
    const [msg, setMsg] = useState('How much are you betting?')
    const [betButton, setBetButton] = useState(true);

    const[forDouble, setForDouble] = useState(false);

    const[savedGames, setSavedGames] = useState(false);

    const[endOfGame, setEndOfGame] = useState(false);

    const[results, setResults] = useState([]);



    // DEALER :
    // declaring a new state variable for the dealer
    const [dealer, setDealer] = useState([]);
    // declaring the state variable for that holds the dealer points
    const [dealerPoints, setDealerPoints] = useState(0);
    // new state variable for optional dealer points
    const [optlDlrPt, setOptlDlrPt] = useState(0);
    const [showOptlDlrPt, setShowOptlDlrPt] = useState(false);
    // back of the dealers card
    const [backOfDealersCard, setBackofDealersCard] = useState(false);



    // variable for the Hit Button
    let hitButton = enablePlayerCards === true && endOfPlayerRound === false && placeGameBet === false;
    // variable for the stand button
    let standButton = endOfPlayerRound === false && enablePlayerCards === true && placeGameBet === false;
    // variable for the double button
    let doubleButton = gamePlayer.length === 2 && endOfPlayerRound === false &&
    placeGameBet === false && playerBalance >= currBet;


    // passing an empty dependencies array to the useEffect hook...
    // ...so it runs only when the component mounts
    useEffect(() => {
        // creating a new deck side effect
        composeNewDeck();
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
            save()
            // cancel the event by the standard
            event.preventDefault();
            // return the value
            return event.returnValue = 'Did you make up your mind?';
        })
        return() => {
            window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
                save()
                // cancel the event by the standard
                event.preventDefault();
                // return the value
              return event.returnValue = 'Did you make up your mind?';
            })
        }
    }, )

    useEffect(() => {
        setPlayerPoints(() => {return 0})
        setOptlPPt(() => {return 0})

        gamePlayer.map((card) => (
            card.value === 'Jack' || card.value === 'King' || card.value === 'Queen' ? (
                setPlayerPoints((points) => { return points + 10}),
                setOptlPPt((points) => { return points + 10})
            ):
            card.value === 'Ace' ? (
                setPlayerPoints((points) => { return points + 11}),
                setOptlPPt((points) => { return points + 1}),
                setShowOptlPPt(() => {return true})
            ):(
                setPlayerPoints((points) => { return points + parseInt(card.value) }),
                setOptlPPt((points) => { return points + parseInt(card.value)})
            )
        ))
    }, [gamePlayer])


    useEffect(() => {
        setDealerPoints(() => {return 0})
        setOptlDlrPt(() => {return 0})

        if (dealer.length === 2 && endOfPlayerRound === false) {
            if (dealer[0].value === 'Jack' ||
            dealer[0].value === 'King' ||
            dealer[0].value === 'Queen' ) {
                setDealerPoints((points) => { return points + 10})
                setOptlDlrPt((points) => { return points + 10})
            } else if (dealer[0].value === 'Ace') {
                setDealerPoints((points) => { return points + 11})
                setOptlDlrPt((points) => { return points + 1})
                setShowOptlDlrPt(() => { return true})
            } else {
                setDealerPoints((points) => { return points + parseInt(dealer[0].value) })
                setOptlDlrPt((points) => { return points + parseInt(dealer[0].value)})
            }
        } else {
            dealer.map((card) => (
                card.value === 'Jack' ||
                card.value === 'King' ||
                card.value === 'Queen' ? (
                    setDealerPoints((points) => { return points + 10}),
                    setOptlDlrPt((points) => { return points + 10})
                ):
                card.value === 'Ace' ? (
                    setDealerPoints((points) => { return points + 11}),
                    setOptlDlrPt((points) => { return points + 1}),
                    setShowOptlDlrPt(() => {return true})
                ): (
                    setDealerPoints((points) => { return points + parseInt(card.value) }),
                    setOptlDlrPt((points) => { return points + parseInt(card.value)})
                )
            ))
        }
    }, [dealer, endOfPlayerRound])

    useEffect(() => {

        if (playerPoints > 21 && optlPPt > 21) {
            setEnablePlayerCards(() => {return false})
            setMsg('Uh Oh...Looks like you lost');
            setTimeout(() => {
                dealerWon();
            }, 2000);
        } else if (playerPoints === 21 || optlPPt === 21) {
            setMsg("Now you see...Blackjack!")
            setEnablePlayerCards(() => {return false})
            setTimeout(() => {
                stand()
            }, 2000);
        } else {
            forDouble === true && stand();
        }
    }, [playerPoints])


    useEffect(() => {
        if ( ((endOfPlayerRound === true && dealerPoints <= 16) ||
                (dealerPoints > 21 && optlDlrPt <= 16)) && dealerPoints !== 0) {
            setMsg("Computers turn");
            draw(false, drawFirstCard);
        } else if (endOfPlayerRound === true && dealerPoints !== 0) {
            let comparePlayersPoint;
            let compareDealerPoint;
            if (playerPoints > 21 && (optlPPt > 0 && optlPPt <= 21) ) {
                comparePlayersPoint = optlPPt;
            } else {
                comparePlayersPoint = playerPoints;
            }

            if( dealerPoints > 21 && optlDlrPt > 21){
                compareDealerPoint = 0;
            } else if (dealerPoints > 21 && (optlDlrPt > 0 && optlDlrPt <= 21)) {
                    compareDealerPoint = optlDlrPt;
            } else if (dealerPoints <= 21) {
                compareDealerPoint = dealerPoints;
            }

            if( (21 - comparePlayersPoint) < (21 - compareDealerPoint) ) {
                setMsg("You won")
                setTimeout(() => {
                    playerWon();
                }, 2000);
            } else if ((21 - comparePlayersPoint) > (21 - compareDealerPoint)){
                setMsg("Computer won")
                setTimeout(() => {
                    dealerWon();
                }, 2000);
            } else {
                setMsg("Draw")
                setTimeout(() => {
                    noWinner();
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
    }, [dealerPoints])


    useEffect(() => {
        if (placeGameBet === true) {
            setMsg("How much are you betting?");
            setBetButton(true);
        }
    }, [placeGameBet])

    useEffect(() => {
        if ( gameRound > 5 ) {
            endGame();
        } else if (gameRound !== 1 && savedGames === false) {
            nextRound();
        } else {
            setSavedGames(false);
        }
    }, [gameRound])


    // calling the Deck Of Cards API to fecth the cards
    const composeNewDeck = () => {
        fetch(deckOfCardsLink + shuffleDeckOfCards + deckAmt, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(responseData => {
                setDeckFilled(() => { return true; })
                setCardDeck( () => { return {...responseData}; })
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log('error : ' + err);
            });
    }

    // calling the Deck Of Cards API to draw a card
    const draw = (forPlayers, amtOfCards) => {
        fetch(deckOfCardsLink + cardDeck.deck_id + amtOfCards, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(responseData => {
                if (forPlayers === true) {
                    setPlayer((playerHand) => { return [...playerHand, ...responseData.cards]; })
                } else {
                    setDealer((dealerHand) => { return [...dealerHand, ...responseData.cards]; })
                }

            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log('error : ' + err);
            });
    }

    // calling the Deck Of Cards API to shuffle the card deck
    const shuffleDeck = (deckId) => {
        fetch(deckOfCardsLink + deckId + reShuffleDeckOfCard, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(responseData => {
                setDeckFilled(() => { return true; })
                setCardDeck( () => { return {...responseData}; })
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log('error : ' + err);
            });
    }


    const stand = () => {
        setBackofDealersCard(() => {return true})
        setTimeout(() => {
            setEndOfPlayerRound(() => {return true})
            setEnablePlayerCards(() => {return false})
        }, 250);
    }

    const double = () => {
        setForDouble(true);
        setMsg("Going for double!")
        setPlayerBalance((balance) => {return balance - currBet})
        setBet((bet) => {return bet+bet})
        draw(true, drawFirstCard);
    }

    const startRound = () => {
        setEndOfPlayerRound(false);
        setEnablePlayerCards(true);
        setPlaceGameBet(false);
        setBetButton(false);
        setMsg("Your turn");
        if (deckFilled === true) {
            draw(true, drawSecondCard);
            draw(false, drawSecondCard);
        }
    }

    const bet = (amount) => {
        if (playerBalance - amount >= 0) {
            setPlayerBalance((balance) => { return balance - amount});
            setBet((bet) => {return bet + amount})
        }
    }

    const playerWon = () => {
        setPlayerBalance((balance) => {return balance + (currBet * 1.5)})
        setGameRound((round) => {return round + 1});
    }

    const dealerWon = () => {
        setGameRound((round) => {return round + 1});
    }

    const noWinner = () => {
        setPlayerBalance((balance) => {return balance + currBet})
        setGameRound((round) => {return round + 1});
    }

    const nextRound = () => {
        setBackofDealersCard(false);
        setForDouble(false);
        setShowOptlDlrPt(false);
        setShowOptlPPt(false);
        setPlayerPoints(0);
        setOptlPPt(0);
        setDealerPoints(0);
        setOptlDlrPt(0);
        setPlaceGameBet(true);
        setBetButton(true);
        setBet(0);
        setPlayer([]);
        setDealer([]);
    }

    const endGame = () => {
        setEndOfGame(true);
        setBet(0);
        setMsg("Game Over");
        let rank = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("rank"));

        if( rank === undefined || rank === null) {
            localStorage.setItem("rank", JSON.stringify({
                points: [playerBalance]
            }))
        } else {
            let sortedRank = rank.points.sort(function(a, b) {
                return b - a;
              })
            if (sortedRank.length<=2) {
                setResults([...sortedRank])
            } else {
                setResults([sortedRank[0],sortedRank[1],sortedRank[2]])
            }
            localStorage.setItem("rank", JSON.stringify({
                points: [...rank.points, playerBalance]
            }))
        }
    }

    const reset = () => {
        setEndOfGame(false);
        setDeckFilled(false);
        shuffleDeck(cardDeck.deck_id);
        nextRound();
        setGameRound(3);
        setPlayerBalance(5000);
    }

    const save = () => {
        localStorage.setItem("savedGame", JSON.stringify(
            {
                deckFilled: deckFilled,
                cardDeck: cardDeck,
                gamePlayer: gamePlayer,
                dealer: dealer,
                playerPoints: playerPoints,
                dealerPoints: dealerPoints,
                optlPPt: optlPPt,
                showOptlPPt: showOptlPPt,
                optlDlrPt: optlDlrPt,
                showOptlDlrPt: showOptlDlrPt,
                enablePlayerCards: enablePlayerCards,
                endOfPlayerRound: endOfPlayerRound,
                playerBalance: playerBalance,
                currBet: currBet,
                backOfDealersCard: backOfDealersCard,
                gameRound: gameRound,
                placeGameBet: placeGameBet,
                msg: msg,
                betButton: betButton,
                forDouble: forDouble,
            }
        ));
    }

    const load = () => {
        setSavedGames(true);
        let gameSave = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedGame'));
        if (gameSave !== undefined) {
            setCardDeck(gameSave.cardDeck);
            setPlayer(gameSave.gamePlayer);
            setDealer(gameSave.dealer);
            setPlayerPoints(gameSave.playerPoints);
            setDealerPoints(gameSave.dealerPoints);
            setOptlPPt(gameSave.optlPPt);
            setShowOptlPPt(gameSave.showOptlPPt);
            setOptlDlrPt(gameSave.optlDlrPt);
            setShowOptlDlrPt(gameSave.showOptlDlrPt);
            setEnablePlayerCards(gameSave.enablePlayerCards);
            setEndOfPlayerRound(gameSave.endOfPlayerRound);
            setPlayerBalance(gameSave.playerBalance);
            setBet(gameSave.currBet);
            setBackofDealersCard(gameSave.backOfDealersCard);
            setGameRound(gameSave.gameRound);
            setPlaceGameBet(gameSave.placeGameBet);
            setMsg(gameSave.msg);
            setBetButton(gameSave.betButton);
            setForDouble(gameSave.forDouble);
            setDeckFilled(gameSave.deckFilled);
        }
    }
```